# ASP.NET system.codedom not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, codedom

I am making a asp.net web-site.

Is there a way that I can put this code:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler 
            language="c#;cs;csharp" 
            extension=".cs" 
            compilerOptions="/unsafe"
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

When I try to put it in it gives an error:

```
Validation (XHTML5): Element 'system.codedom' is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this work

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
    <compiler 
        language="c#;cs;csharp" 
        extension=".cpp" 
        compilerOptions="/unsafe"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</compilers>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you changed and why it should work now? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well it didn't work